# How to use ftp to update database for Maui

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ftp, maui

I have a trouble within update database (embedded) for Maui App,before I add existing file `database.db` for my Maui project with embedded resource. And now I delete this `database.db` and then use FTP server to download this `database.db`, but my app can't catch binding data.

You can see here (I named as version 1.0) to connect sqlite database, and my app catch binding data well:

```
public static string DatabasePath => 
   Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath
  (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), DatabaseFilename);

private SQLiteConnection _connection;
public SQLiteConnection Connection => _connection ??= new 
       SQLiteConnection(ConstantsInfo.DatabasePath);

public  void Initialize()
{
    //1.open target file to filestream
    using var dbFileStream = new FileStream(ConstantsInfo.DatabasePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    //2.open resource file database -->resourcestream
    using var dbAssetStream = typeof(ProdottiStorage)
 .Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Dataoffline."+ConstantsInfo.DatabaseFilename);
    //3.copy resource stream to filestream 
    dbAssetStream.CopyTo(dbFileStream);
   }
```

and NOW (version 2.0) I want update my database -> database.db(samename,but diffirent data), so I delete old `database.db` and download new `database.db` from ftp server, the code is here:

```
public RelayCommand _yesupdate;
public RelayCommand YesUpdate => _yesupdate ??= new 
RelayCommand(() =>
    {
     // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
      FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpInfo.IPV4 + @"/" + ftpInfo.FileName);

     request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
     //login
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpInfo.UseName, ftpInfo.Pwd);

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            content = content.ToUpperInvariant();
            string targetFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), ftpInfo.FileName);
        
            using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
            using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
            streamWriter.Write(content);
           
            Alert.Execute(null);
       
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
```

The result is my APP could not get data,when but the ftp server show I download successful, my Android device can not find `database.db`, just can see a void file (cache)

Answer (score 0):

Need to correspond to the above method of processing the database which (in
public  void Initialize())

```
  public RelayCommand _yesupdate;
  public RelayCommand YesUpdate => _yesupdate ??= new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        string serverPath = "ftp://" + ftpInfo.IPV4 + @"/" + 
        ftpInfo.FileName;

        string destinationFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), ftpInfo.FileName);

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverPath);

        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpInfo.UseName, ftpInfo.Pwd);
           // Read the file from the server & write to destination                
        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
           //2.open resource file database -->resourcestream 
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
```

change code here,because before database.db is embedded resource,we also use the same way to open   //1.open target file to filestream and copyto   //3.copy resource stream to filestream

```
 using (var dbFileStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, 
 FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            responseStream.CopyTo(dbFileStream);

        }
    
        Alert.Execute(null);
    });
```

here  https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp